# chrome v62 enable flash

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, flash, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium (v2.53) test that visits a site containing flash player (I'm testing this player). up until now, everything was working fine, but after I updated chrome to v62, flash is disabled by default.
I can't change manually flash setting since this test is automated and running on remote machines.

I've tried adding some chrome capabilities that should work on previous versions of chrome, but it did not work on chrome 62 version since allowing flash is not enough, now a list of allowed site is also required.

How can I change both the enabled status and the list of sites using selenium?

Also, is there a way to install chrome with a config file that both enables flash and populates the required sites list?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm working with Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to simply use Chrome options.  Why do you need a config file?  That sounds overly complicated and unnecessary.  You can enable it through chrome preferences.  Try a fresh install of Chrome too.

Something akin to the likes of:

```
 chromeOptions:{
      args: ["--allow-running-insecure-content", "--allow-insecure-websocket-from-https-origin", "allow-outdated-plugins"]
```

You didn't specify which language so I can't give you a language example.

Comment: sorry, I'm using Java. I've tried those args and it didn't work for me on the new chrome version. any other way?

Comment: @N.yaron Not sure sorry.